# The meaning of colon operator in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I came across some MATLAB syntax with a colon that I don't fully understand.

#### First Question:

The expression: `0:pi/4:pi`
results in the answer: `0    0.7854    1.5708    2.3562    3.1416`

Why is this the case? I thought that colon operator is used as a quick way to refer to indices so that we don't have to write out the full list. (e.g. `1:3` -> `1 2 3`)

#### Second Question:

Similar to above, say if I have a matrix `X = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`. How can I interpret the expression `X(:,1:3)`? Specifically, what does the colon operator without the left and right numbers mean?

Comment: You should read this article by @Loren titled "All about the Colon Operator": http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `a:b` generates a vector. You could use it as index only because the `(...)` accepts a list also, e.g.

```
octave-3.0.3:10> a = [1,4,7]
a =

   1   4   7

octave-3.0.3:11> b = [1,4,9,16,25,36,49]
b =

    1    4    9   16   25   36   49

octave-3.0.3:12> b(a)    # gets [b(1), b(4), b(7)]
ans =

    1   16   49
```

Now, the `a:b:c` syntax is equivalent to `[a, a+b, a+2*b, ...]` until `c`, e.g.

```
octave-3.0.3:15> 4:7:50
ans =

   4  11  18  25  32  39  46
```

which explains what you get in `0:pi/4:pi`.

---

A lone `:` selects the whole axes (row/column), e.g.

```
octave-3.0.3:16> a = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9]
a =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

octave-3.0.3:17> a(:,1)   # means a(1:3, 1)
ans =

   1
   4
   7

octave-3.0.3:18> a(1,:)   # means a(1, 1:3)
ans =

   1   2   3
```

---

See the official MATLAB doc on [colon (:)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) for detail.

Comment: @KennyTM: Remember that `a:b:c` is not always the same as `[a a+b a+b+b .. c]`; try this example: `x=0; for i=1:10, x=x+0.1; end` then if you compare `x==1` it will return false, due to accumulated floating-point inaccuracies (in fact `abs(x-1)` is something to the order of `1e-16`)

Comment: @Amro: I don't think your for loop has anything to do with the `a:b:c` syntax.

Comment: @KennyTM: Well if you want to be exact, then compare `y = 0:0.1:1;` to the for-loop: `x(1)=0; for i=1:10, x(i+1)=x(i)+0.1; end`, and you will see that `all(x==y)` is not always true

Comment: @Amro: Right, but `a:b:c` is constructed using http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4FLI96/index.html?solution=1-4FLI96

Comment: @KennyTM: that's exactly the point I'm trying to make: the colon operator in this case does not do repeated additions, rather it is careful to arrange that the last element is exactly the end number..

Answer (score 0):

My two pennies to KennyTM's answer.

Actually scalar and vector variables in MATLAB have 2 dimensions. Scalar has 1 row and 1 column, and vector has either 1 row or column. Just try `size(X)`.

Colon (`:`) operator for indexing simply means **all**. Syntax `X(:,1:3)` means get all rows and columns from 1 to 3. Since your variable `X` has only 1 row, you will get first 3 values in this row.

Comment: Matrices can have arbitrary dimensionality; e.g. `A=rand(6,5,4,8,3)` creates a 5-dimensional matrix with random digits. Doing `A(:,2,4,:,2)` is then a perfectly reasonable syntax to get a specific 2D slice from that 5D matrix.

Comment: By MATLAB definition "All MATLAB variables are multidimensional arrays, no matter what type of data. **A matrix is a two-dimensional array** often used for linear algebra." [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.htm). Also try `ismatrix(rand(2,3,2))`. You are right that colon operator can be applied to any dimension of an array.

Comment: Let me even add more: Try `x=1;size(x,4567)`

Comment: Exactly as in my comment: "All MATLAB variables are multidimensional arrays". I just oppose using term matrix for an array with more than 2 dimensions.