# What does this line of Matlab code mean?

Tags: matlab

I'm new to Matlab, and I'm trying to unscrabble the code [here](http://www-scf.usc.edu/~mohammab/codes/iLasso.m). In particular, I'm wondering what this line does:

```
ti = (Series{1}(2, i) - L*Dt):Dt:(Series{1}(2, i)-Dt);
```

In particular, what does the colon do? I found [this explanation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_syntax.htm):

[image]

But to me this doesn't tell me what it's doing here. Similarly, I'm not even clear on what `Series{1}(2, i) - L*Dt` produces. I get that normally the answer would be 'try it out', but I don't have access to Matlab and so would appreciate any comments or advice.

Thank you.

Comment: @TroyHaskin i agree with you but maybe it's the cell array that makes the statement look more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces are used for [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html?refresh=true), a data-structure that can hold any type. In this case, I think it's a safe guess that Series{1} contains a matrix, so `Series{1}(2,i)` is just a specific entry. Writing this out step-by-step might be the easiest to understand:

```
A = Series{1} % get the matrix
t0 = A(2,i) - L*Dt;
tN = A(2, i) - Dt;
ti = t0:Dt:tN; % create a time-series from time t0 to tN, with step-size Dt
```

Answer (score 1):

in the linked code it says `Each cell is a 2xT matrix. First row contains the values and the second row contains SORTED time stamps. The first time series is the target time series which is predicted.`

`Series{1}(2, i)` fetches the i-th time stamp (`(2,i)` means), in the first time series (`{1}` means) (which i guess is used as a reference frame), and let's think that it is a certain given number `T0`.

The second step of the code is to establish a time array, starting from `T0 - L*Dt` and stops at `T0 - *Dt`. The length of each increment is `Dt`.

It's same as [The meaning of colon operator in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991362/the-meaning-of-colon-operator-in-matlab) as pointed out by @TroyHaskin . But i think it's the cell array that makes it less easy to understand.

Comment: yes! thanks very much fort his clear explanation.